# How to find the NotSupportedException root cause?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have a netcoreapp2.0 test project running against a .net 4.6.1 project. I've started having NotSupportedException thrown on all tests in this project after installing the 3.0 SDK. On machines with only older SDKs or specifying the 2.2 SDK on the global.json file it works.

My point is, how can I find what is throwing the exception? It's being thrown inside a DLL which I don't own and I can't use sourcelink. VS is not displaying any stacktrace and it doesn't stop on the exception even with CLR exceptions set for every exception.

This is the only result I get, by running the tests.

```sh
PS (...)> dotnet test
Test run for (...).Tests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.3.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...

A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.35]     (...) [FAIL]
  X (...) [1ms]
  Error Message:
   System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.

[xUnit.net 00:00:01.43]     (...) [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.43]     (...) [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.43]     (...) [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.43]     (...) [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.43]     (...) [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.43]     (...) [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.43]     (...) [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.43]     (...) [FAIL]
  X (...) [1ms]
  Error Message:
   System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.

  X (...) [1ms]
  Error Message:
   System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.

  X (...) [1ms]
  Error Message:
   System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.

  X (...) [1ms]
  Error Message:
   System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.

  X (...) [1ms]
  Error Message:
   System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.

  X (...) [1ms]
  Error Message:
   System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.

  X (...) [1ms]
  Error Message:
   System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.

  X (...) [1ms]
  Error Message:
   System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.

(REPEATS FOR ALL THE TESTS...)

Test Run Failed.
Total tests: 30
     Failed: 30
 Total time: 3,2953 Seconds
```

**Update:**
I don't know how or why after updating the VS to 16.3.9 (I was on 16.3.8) and/or restarting the machine it didn't happen anymore. All the tests are now working without any modification to the source.

```sh
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

```sh
Test run for (...).Tests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.3.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...

A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 431
     Passed: 431
 Total time: 10,5425 Seconds
```

Although I couldn't reproduce the error in the exact same scenario, I could get the same error message on purpose and perhaps it's related.
All our tests are decorated with `Xunit.TheoryAttribute`, a couple of `Xunit.TraitAttribute` and many `JsonDataSourceAttribute`. This last one is developed inhouse and creates a test scenario from a JSON file, pretty much like `DataSourceAttribute` does (like explained on [How to: Create a data-driven unit test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2019)).
Even activating "Break When Thrown" and adding breakpoints on the test method and constructor, when the test scenario file can't be found I get this same error message and no stacktrace is provided.

```
TestClassName
   Source: (...)Test.cs line 35
   Duration: 1 ms

  Message: 
    System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.
```

Perhaps the previous problem was related to the files not being copied to the output, but I still don't know why I don't get a stacktrace or a more specific error related to the file not being found. I'll check the attribute source and verify if it could be improved and if it's, somehow, hiding the issue.

Comment: When debugging you can stop at the location where exception is thrown.

Comment: It only stops on the assertion (perhaps because of an IEnumerable computation) and I get no stacktrace, only this message.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a try-catch and observing the thrown exception in debug mode?

Comment: It's weird that debugger does not break on thrown exceptions, even though it is set to break, as you said. Could it be that the exception is thrown in another process, and the debugged process just receives some kind of notification about it? Could it be that you did not properly set the debugger to break on thrown exceptions (in Ctrl+Alt+E window)?

Comment: BTW, you also have to uncheck "Enable Just My Code" in Tools > Options > Debugging > General.

Comment: @JLRishe the exception isn't thrown inside the test or constructor.

Comment: I don't know why or how it started working after updating VS and/or restarting the machine. I'll add more details. I can't reproduce the exact same scenario again, but I could find a scenario where the breakpoints and stop on exception don't get triggered.

Comment: @Dialecticus "Enable Just My Code" was checked, indeed. Disabling it makes it easier to find the issue inside xUnit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the `JsonDataSourceAttribute` source to the same solution I could make it stop where it should (on the "file not found", in this case).

This is the original source. The exception (when forced to happen) is thrown on `if (!File.Exists(inputfile))`, but `Xunit.Sdk.DataAttribute` hides it.

```cs
    public sealed class JsonDataSourceAttribute : DataAttribute
    {
        public string InputFilePath { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves a collection of context data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputFilePath">Json source file path</param>
        public JsonDataSourceAttribute(string inputFilePath)
        {
            this.InputFilePath = inputFilePath;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
        {
            if (testMethod == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(testMethod)); }

            var inputfile = Path.IsPathRooted(this.InputFilePath)
                ? this.InputFilePath
                : Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), this.InputFilePath);

            if (!File.Exists(inputfile))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Input file not found at '{inputfile}'.");
            }

            return this.LoadFileData(inputfile, this.EnumMap);
        }

        (...)
    }
```

By moving the file existence check to the constructor, I was able to get what I wanted.

```cs
        public JsonDataSourceAttribute(string inputFilePath)
        {
            var inputfile = Path.IsPathRooted(inputFilePath)
                ? inputFilePath
                : Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), inputFilePath);

            if (!File.Exists(inputfile))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Input file not found at '{inputfile}'.");
            }

            this.InputFilePath = inputfile;
        }
```

This is not the "find the root cause" answer, but I guess it wouldn't be possible since the original exception is omitted on `Xunit.Sdk.DataAttribute`.

Comment: Thank you, this lead me to the right place, the json file needs a build action of "content"